# Show out of stock products website based

Tags: websites, out-of-stock, scope

I am having a problem of displaying out of stock products website based.

In admin `System -> Configuration -> Inventory`, there's a field call `Display Out of Stock Products`. But it is a *global field* meaning that we cannot set it in *website scope*.

I am running 2 sites using the same Magento instance.

My question is: Is there anyway to show out of stock products only for a specific website?

Answer (score 0):

this will return you out of stock collection base on current website

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addWebsiteFilter()
                    ->joinField(
                            'is_in_stock',
                            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                            'is_in_stock',
                            'product_id=entity_id',
                            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                            'left'
                    )
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 0));
```